# Why E[E[Y|X]] = E[Y]

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I don't understand how the expected value of the conditional expectation of Y given x is equal to the Expected value of Y.
How should I prove it?

If we sustitute the values in probabilities density functions we have that

E[E[Y|X]] = SUM (E[Y|X=x]) * P(X=x)

Which is...

E[E[Y|X]] = SUM (INTEGER(-INF, INF) Xf(x|y)dx) * P(X=x)

Then the E[E[Y|X]] is the summatory of the integer Xf(x|y)dx times the probability of X when X is x?

How could I apply this in a real example, let's say throwing 2 dice

Comment: This is called the "tower rule", you'll find multiple proofs of it on Wikipedia/YouTube, if you're interested.

Comment: This is *Adam's law* and you can find the proof in Page 396 of *Introduction to Probability* by Joseph K. Blitzstein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have sums in your question I will assume that you work with discrete random variables. In that case we can do the calculation
$$
\begin{align}
E[E[Y|X]]&=\sum_xE[Y|X=x]\cdot P(X=x) \\
&=\sum_x\sum_yy\cdot P(Y=y|X=x)\cdot P(X=x) \\
&=\sum_x\sum_yy\cdot P(Y=y,X=x) \\
&=\sum_yy\sum_xP(Y=y,X=x) \\
&=\sum_yy\cdot P(Y=y) \\
&=E[Y].
\end{align}
$$
So basically the good old trick; whenever you encounter two sums you should probably swap them. Note that this is allowed here if we assume that $E[Y]$ exists.